# steps required to run Docker image using kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have developed a simple Docker image. This can be run using command

```
docker run -e VOLUMEDIR=agentsvolume -v /c/Users/abcd/config:/agentsvolume app-agent
```

Same thing if I want to run using kubernetes, can someone guide me what are the steps to do it?
Do I must create Pods/ Controller or service.. am not able to get clear steps to run using Kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

This kubernetes command is the equivalent to your docker run command:

```
kubectl run --image=app-agent app-agent --env="VOLUMEDIR=agentsvolume"
```

This will create a deployment called app-agent.

Comment: I am passing a mount point as well  -v /c/Users/abcd/config:/agentsvolume